# Lots of styles after angular update

Tags: angular, angular-material

Updated Angular from version 10 to 16 (And updated angular material).
On the 10th version, in the console, not as many styles were used as in 16.
What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

in the 16th version there are a lot of styles on the `body`, such as:

```
    --mat-paginator-container-text-font: Roboto, monospace;
    --mat-paginator-container-text-line-height: 20px;
    --mat-paginator-container-text-size: 12px;
    --mat-paginator-container-text-tracking: .0333333333em;
    --mat-paginator-container-text-weight: 400;
    --mat-paginator-select-trigger-text-size: 12px;
--mdc-filled-text-field-label-text-font: Roboto, monospace;
    --mdc-filled-text-field-label-text-size: 16px;
```

**_material.variables.scss**:

```
@include mat.core();
@include mat.all-component-typographies();

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$teal-palette);
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
 primary: $my-primary,
 accent: $my-accent,
 warn: $my-warn,
),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
 density: 0,
));


$background: map-get($my-theme, background);
$foreground: map-get($my-theme, foreground);

/* stylelint-disable function-parentheses-space-inside */

$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Roboto, monospace',
  $headline-5: mat.define-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400),
  $body-2: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400)
);

/* stylelint-enable */

$config: mat.define-typography-config();

@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
```

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem exactly? Are those styles incorrect? Are they different than what you have in your config? Why do you think there's "too many" of them, what do you think would be the "good number" of them and why?

Comment: In the old version, the tab used only 25 MB of memory.
The new one has about 60-70 MB, it seems to me that this is a lot, maybe I’m wrong?

Comment: Okay. So do I understand correctly that your problem is actually more accurately described as: "after Angular upgrade, the browser tab consumes 4 times more memory than previously, and I don't know if that's normal"?

Comment: In general, yes.
And is it normal that the body tag is mentioned about 10 times, with different styles, as I indicated earlier?

Comment: It might be normal, I don't know. I suggest you close this question and open a new, rephrased one where someone could analyze and explain to you if your observations are to be expected after this upgrade or not.